# How to get all dates between two dates?

Tags: mysql

Please look at my `books` table:

**`books`**

```
+-----+----------+------------+------------+
| id  | venue_id | from_date  | to_date    |
+-----+----------+------------+------------+
|  1  |  8       | 2015-07-21 | 2015-07-28 |
|  2  |  5       | 2015-08-03 | 2015-08-25 |
+-----+----------+------------+------------+
```

I want to view all dates between `from_date` and `to_date` for which `venue_id` = `8`

My output should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
             [id] => 1
             [venue_id] => 8
             [today] => 2015-07-21
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
             [id] => 1
             [venue_id] => 8
             [today] => 2015-07-22
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
             [id] => 1
             [venue_id] => 8
             [today] => 2015-07-23
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
             [id] => 1
             [venue_id] => 8
             [today] => 2015-07-24
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
             [id] => 1
             [venue_id] => 8
             [today] => 2015-07-25
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
             [id] => 1
             [venue_id] => 8
             [today] => 2015-07-26
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
             [id] => 1
             [venue_id] => 8
             [today] => 2015-07-27
        )
)
```

`today` calculates from `from_date` date to `to_date` date. But my mind is blank about that query. How to write a MySQL query to get output like the output shown above?

Comment: Your output omits the end date — is that correct?  So no data should be shown if the start date and the end date are the same?  Or do you ensure that the end date is always a later date than the start date?  Are you open to creating a table listing dates?  It then becomes easy.  Otherwise, it is not easy.

Answer (score 2):

I think the below query should fetch the results. Though I haven't tested the query.

```
select b.id,b.venue_id,d.date from books b 
join
(select a.Date, "8" as venue_id2
from (
select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (1000 * c.a)) DAY as Date
from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) a
where a.Date between '2010-01-20' and '2010-01-24') d on d.venue_id2 = b.venue_id and b.venue_id = 8
```

Comment: A part of the answer is from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range. Just in case you need.

Comment: I am getting this error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'join select a.Date as today from ( select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b' at line 2`

Answer (score 0):

Following query should be use to get desired result.
           select * from books where venue_id=8 and from_date>='2015-07-21' and to_date<='2015-07-27'

Comment: How does that generate the record for 2015-07-23?

Comment: can you let me know what will be logic to calculate today from from_date and to_date

Comment: I don't have a better solution on hand than a table containing one row for each date in the range that's relevant to the application on hand.  It isn't a very big table, even if your data goes back to Roman times and forward to the end of the 10th millennium (less than 5 million rows; more likely, a lot less than 500,000 rows).

Comment: if you leave to_date field and concentrate only one table then we can use between clause to get list of data by range of dates like  select * from books where venue_id=8 and from_date between '2015-07-21' and '2015-07-27'

Comment: How do you generate the seven rows of output data from one row of input data?  Remember, in the general case, there could be a longer gap than seven days, and different rows in the table would generate different numbers of rows in the output.

Comment: venue_id and date range will be dynamic and will change according to need. query structure will remain same to get that.

Comment: At least one of us is missing the point of the question — or, at least, we have different and apparently irreconcilable views on what the question entails, or the mechanisms that can be used to provide the answer.  I won't be responding for a while — 8 hours or more.